# After upgrading to Rails 4 Ckeditor gives undefined method `get!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

After upgrading to Rails 4, the following code broke the site giving the error `undefined method`get!'`

```
 first_image_url = (Ckeditor.picture_model.get!(first_image_id.to_i)).url(:postthumb)
 first_image_url_sidethumb = (Ckeditor.picture_model.get!(first_image_id.to_i)).url(:sidethumb)
```

Full code :
    first_image = post.content[/img.*?src="(.*?)"/i,1]

```
if first_image != nil
    first_image_id = first_image[/\/([-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)\//i,1]
end

if first_image_id != nil && first_image_id.to_i != 0
    first_image_url = (Ckeditor.picture_model.get!(first_image_id.to_i)).url(:postthumb)
    first_image_url_sidethumb = (Ckeditor.picture_model.get!(first_image_id.to_i)).url(:sidethumb)
end
```

Full error :

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `get!' for #<Class:0x0000000582a050>:
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
  app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb___648444255310301698_70033571991640'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:399:in `block in collection_with_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `map'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `collection_with_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:291:in `render_collection'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:275:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:274:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  app/views/layouts/_homesidebar.html.erb:56:in `_app_views_layouts__homesidebar_html_erb___364574751837056606_70033571639420'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:66:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1797376051046499378_40338660'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__3033334921592121089__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__2402224635829105544__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/pubudu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'



Started POST "/__better_errors/70033572179800/variables" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-27 19:52:26 +0530
```

The line `app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8` :

```
first_image_url = (Ckeditor.picture_model.get!(first_image_id.to_i)).url(:postthumb)
```

Comment: Could you past whole error together with backtrace?

Comment: @BroiSatse I just added the error log :)

Comment: Ty, could you also show this line: `app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:8` with anything which is relevant to it?

Comment: @BroiSatse Just added that line :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `.get!` with `find` and it works :)

The fixed code :

```
first_image_url = (Ckeditor.picture_model.find(first_image_id.to_i)).url(:postthumb)
```